# Phonegap + Phaser game shuts down background audio on iOS

Tags: cordova, phaser-framework

I'm developing a simple game. I want players to be able to listen their music while playing game. On Android there is no problem but on iOS, as soon as app loads sound is gone.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983463/avoid-stopping-background-audio-for-howler-js-sprite-playback-on-ios) but it's related to use of howler.js. I don't use it. I use Phaser's built-in audio manager.

Actually even if I exclude all sound related code, still it mutes background music.

Is there an option in XCode or some plugin of phonegap? I've been searching for it for days.

Edit: Code about sound manager is here:

At preload state:
`this.load.audio('score', ['sounds/score.ogg', 'sounds/score.mp3']);`

When I play it:

`var scoreSound = game.add.audio('score');
scoreSound.play();`

Comment: i don't know about ios, or if it's compatible with phonegap, but i've successfully used [this cordova plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio) with my games.

Comment: so, when you use this plugin it doesn't mute other apps' sounds?

Comment: Are you using iOS9 or better?

Comment: iOS 8.4 I use and want my game be able to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122363/iphone-app-allow-background-music-to-continue-to-play?lq=1). Actually I figured it out that it is the same way you do in objective-c. Someone who knows how to develop plugin for Phonegap can convert this into a plugin, which would be very helpful who has no idea about obj-c.